# What HTTP response code and header should be given for a batch job?

Tags: .net, http, rest, http-headers, webclient

I am polling for the status of a given REST batch job with this API call

```
GET https://xxx.egnyte.com/pubapi/v1/audit/jobs/1381774131181 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer 3ysd8zxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Type: application/json
Host: xxx.egnyte.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The HTTP response is this:

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Date: Mon, 14 Oct 2013 18:12:29 GMT
Server: Mashery Proxy
Set-Cookie: EGNYTE-MARKETING-SESSION-COOKIE=1; path=/; domain=egnyte.com
Set-Cookie: X-Egnyte-Subdomain=xxx; path=/; domain=egnyte.com; expires=Tue, 14-Oct-2014 18:12:29 GMT
X-Mashery-Responder: avl-mashery-master
Location: https://haproxy:7180/public-api/v1/audit/logins/1381774131181
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
P3P: CP="NOI DSP COR NID CUR TAIa OUR NOR" policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml"
Set-Cookie: EGNYTE-MARKETING-COOKIE=22.22.186.9.138333333885; path=/; expires=Tue, 14-Oct-14 18:12:29 GMT; domain=.egnyte.com
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1333398F4E959E33333F2EA0DB1.avl-app17_6280; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
X-Robots-Tag: none
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

16
{"status":"completed"}
0
```

.NET seems to be confused by this response, and issues the following:

[image]

Obviously .NET is not seeing the HTTP 303 above, and is instead reporting a 502 by looking at the Location URL, which isn't available from internet clients.

**Question**

- What SHOULD the HTTP response to this be? (I'm polling for a status, what should be altered or removed?)
- How can I get .NET to play nicely so that I can extract the JSON embedded in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say what the response *should* be (too little context), but to process the 303 response itself and not follow through to the `Location` URL you need to lose a level of abstraction: use a [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.HttpWebRequest.aspx) and set [`AllowAutoRedirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx) to `false`.

For example:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you should never server `303 See Other; Location: private-url` to a public client.

You should either not serve such response at all.

If you want to use local urls inside your DC, then your front-end server, e.g. reverse proxy should change the response into `403 Forbidden` for example, because that's what private url means.

Other alternatives are `202 Accepted`, or `204 No Content` because semantically server has accepted the request and refuses to divulge the response.